# 'name [x] not defined' during 'if' function

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and experimenting using Atom and Python3.9. I am trying to create a basic time zone converter, from EST to 4 locations. I am receiving a traceback on the 2nd to last of the following lines (*if dest==London:*), with the message "*NameError: name 'London' is not defined*". The message refers to '*London*' regardless of which city is inputted.

```
    # time difference from EST
    lhrs = int(input("EST hours 24hr clock"))
    lmin = int(input("EST minutes"))
    local = (f"{lhrs}:{lmin}")
    print(f"local time is {local}")
    dest = input("Set Destination, London, Rome, Mumbai or Sydney:")
    if dest==London:
        dhrs = lhrs+5
```

I appreciate there are probably many things I could improve in this, but for now I would appreciate advice on why this traceback error is occurring. There are several lines of code after those I have entered, which I can share if it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Lee

Answer (score 1):

you probably meant to do :

```
if dest=='London':
```

There is a big difference between a string in quotes (as I have suggested) and a name without quotes.

Your code is looking for a variable called `London` - where as you need to be comparing `dest` to the string `'London'`

Answer (score 1):

That's because the python interpreter assumes you are referring to the variable London, of which there is none.
What you are comparing is the user input, which comes in as a string.
So putting "" around London should do the trick, like so;

```
if dest=="London":
    dhrs = lhrs+5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put London in quotes I.e “London”
Without quotes python thinks you mean a variable called London.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, the quotation marks...
In this case `London` is a variable, not a string, so you have to define the variable `London`, or directly transform it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around strings, otherwise python looks for a variable with the same name. You want:

```
if dest.lower() == 'london':
    #rest
```

Never rely on or require the user to type capital letters unless it's a password.

Answer (score 0):

London is not a variable so you have to compare to the string London, like:

```
if dest=="London":
        dhrs = lhrs+5
```

if you don´t wanna compare to the string you can create a variable with the content "Londo" like

```
london="London"
if dest==london:
        dhrs = lhrs+5
```